# Jersey RESTful Service 500 Error (request is null)

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm a new in REST services and I want to make test with Jersey Test Framework. 
Configuration seems to be ok (not null) but debugger has shown that the request is null. Changing paths in **target()**-method gave nothing.
Found many answers but they did not help. So why request can be null?

TestReportResource.java

```
public class TestReportResource extends JerseyTest {
    private ETS tmEts;
    private ETS suEts;
    private ReportService mockReportService;
    private ReportResource reportResource;
    private ReportResource reportResourceNew;
    private MapperFacade mapper;
    private ReportServiceJerseyMockTest mockReportServiceJersey;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        this.tmEts = TestUtils.loginAs(TestUtils.PURE_TM, TestUtils.PASSWORD_COMMON);
        this.suEts = TestUtils.loginAs(TestUtils.PURE_SU, TestUtils.PASSWORD_COMMON);
        this.mapper = EntityMapperFactory.getMapper();

        this.mockReportService = mock(ReportService.class);
        this.reportResource = new ReportResource(this.mockReportService, this.mapper);
    }


    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
        return new JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        this.mockReportServiceJersey = new ReportServiceJerseyMockTest(); **//fields are here, because init() initiates later than configure()**
        this.reportResource = new ReportResource(this.mockReportServiceJersey, this.mapper);

        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(ReportResource.class);

        AbstractBinder binder = new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(ReportServiceJerseyMockTest.class).to(IReportService.class);
            }
        };
        config.register(binder);
        return config;
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetProjectManagersRestJersey() {

        List<ManagerUserEntity> testList = (List<ManagerUserEntity>) new ReportServiceJerseyMockTest().getProjectManagers(tmEts, "login");

        ManagerUserEntity managerUserEntity = target("/reports/project-managers").request().get(ManagerUserEntity.class); **// request equals to null**

        assertEquals(testList, mapper.mapAsList(List of entities received from ReportResource.getProjectManagers, ManagerUserEntity.class));
        (not ended)
    }

}
```

ReportResource.java - the resource class which is under testing

```
@Path("/reports/")
public class ReportResource {
    @Inject
    private IReportService reportService;
    private MapperFacade mapper;


    @GET
    @Path("project-managers")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Collection<ManagerUserDTO> getProjectManagers(@Context  HttpServletRequest request, 
                                 @DefaultValue("All") 
                                 @QueryParam("lmLogin") String lmLogin) {

        ETS ets = (ETS) request.getAttribute("ets"); **// request equals null**

        Collection<ManagerUserEntity> entities = this.reportService.getProjectManagers(ets, lmLogin);

        return mapper.mapAsList(entities, ManagerUserDTO.class);
    }

}
```

StackTrace

```
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1020)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:816)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
    at test.rest.TestReportResource.testGetProjectManagersRestJersey(TestReportResource.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message and/or stack trace as well?

Comment: As I understand  - it doesn't inject my Resourse.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple problems

First, [`JerseyTest` already has a `@Before` method](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/test-framework/core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/test/JerseyTest.java#L603) where it calls you `configure` method create the Jersey application. This `@Before` is called before *your* `@Before`, so any application configuration *should not* be done in this method. It is OK to use for things used in your `@Test` methods.

Second, you have not configured your `MapperFacade`. So your resource class never gets it. I imagine this is the cause of the 500 (the main cause being an NPE). So do two things

1. Initialize the `MapperFacade` in the `configure` method of the `JerseyTest`, then configure it in the `configure` method of the `AbstractBinder`

   ```
   final MapperFacade mapper = EntityMapper.getMapper();
   AbstractBinder binder = new AbstractBinder() {
       @Override
       protected void configure() {
           ...
           bind(mapper).to(MapperFacade.class);
       }
   };
   ```
2. Add the `@Inject` annotation to it in the resource class

   ```
    public class ReportResource {
        @Inject
        private MapperFacade mapper;
   ```

As an aside, when getting a 500 Server Error, and there is no stack trace (for the *real* exception), often is is swallowed by the framework and converted to a framework specific exception, which isn't much help, like in your case. In situations like this, I just add a debugging `ExceptionMapper`, that prints the stack trace. This should give you some information

```
@Provider
public static class DebugMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
    @Overrride
    public Response toResponse(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}

@Override
public Application configure() {
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(..);
    config.register(DebugMapper.class);
}
```