# RESTfull API using jersey -Getting HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, internal-server-error, tomcat9, rest

I am new to Rest API web service. I have tired to create simple REST API using jersey Library. It is call the resource page. but its not return the value.

It shows:- HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

plus warning message in console :- WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [316] milliseconds.

My Resource:

```
package com.msfathi.messenger.resources;

import java.util.List;

import com.msfathi.messenger.model.MessageModel;
import com.msfathi.messenger.service.MessageService;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {
    
    MessageService messageService=new MessageService();
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<MessageModel> getMessage(){
        
        System.out.println("messageresource is called");
        return messageService.getAllMessages();
        
    }

}
```

I got That **messageresource is called** output in console, but i did not got return value

console:

```
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [321] milliseconds.
Jan 09, 2021 6:21:39 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 09, 2021 6:21:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 09, 2021 6:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [3949] milliseconds
messageresource is called
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.msfathi</groupId>
    <artifactId>messenger</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>messenger</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>messenger</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>3.0.0-M1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.msfathi.messenger</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Look at the bottom of this post. Take the DebugMapper and put it in the messenger folder. Then make the request again. Maybe this time you will get a stack trace in your log. If you do get one, it should tell you what the problem is. If you can't figure it out still, post the stack trace here.

Comment: It might've helped if I actually provided [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33393959/2587435) lol. Sorry.